# Unable to set the correct values for Sencha Touch dual slider

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I'm trying to implement the Sencha Touch dual range slider to replace a current jQuery Mobile implementation of the same functionality due to performance reasons.

I don't seem to be able to correctly set the values / maxValue on the slider. Given that I took my first look at Sencha a few hours ago i'm not sure if I'm missing something or not.

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sZ96p/) demonstrating the problem i'm having.

The second handle doesn't appear to display past the halfway mark in this situation using:

```
minValue: 0,
maxValue: 200,
values: [30, 165]
```

Answer (score 0):

Sliderfield supports only values between the range 0 - 100. I dont know why this is so (maybe a bug or flaw with Sencha). If you use a slider instead of a sliderfield this problem will not occur. So you should recalibrate your slider like this

```
{
xtype: 'selectfield',
increment: 0.5
}
```

Hope it helps